# Cannot able to fetch data from ajax to php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, ajaxform

I design a simple page were user can put name, password and image using html.
I try to sent those data using ajax to specific php page, but I cannot implement this.
how I do this thing

Html code

```
<?php include('connection.php'); ?>         
    <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="name" id="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" id="pass"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Photos:</td>
                <td><input type="file" id="photos"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="go"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Jquery and ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#go').click(function(){      
            var img_name = $('#img_name').val();
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var pass = $('#pass').val();  
            $.ajax({   
                type : "POST",
                url : "singup_submit.php",
                data : { img_name:img_name, name:name, pass:pass},
                success : function(done){
                    alert(done);
                }    
            });    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Php code

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');    
    if(isset($_POST)){   
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $img_name=$_FILES['img_name']['name'];

        $qr="INSERT INTO data (name,pass,img_name) VALUES ('$name','$pass','$img_name')";
        $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qr) or die(mysqli_error($con));    
        if($ex==1)
            echo 'done';
        else            
            echo 'not done';
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Please use a prepared statements in your php code to prevent sql injections https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php

Comment: No I dont get any errors, but the file name not update on data base,but name and pass are update

Comment: You are not sending any files in your ajax request, you are just sending a file name. So in your php code the array `$_FILES` is empty.

Comment: so what is the salutation @theblackips

Comment: Why do you use ajax anyway? Can't you just submit the form the normal way?

Comment: i just want to learn how send file using ajax ans also lode this file using ajax

Comment: Please refer to this tutorial https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax (or similar ones) and come back if you run into further problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195801/discussion-between-toufik-khan-and-theblackips).

Comment: Please refer a proper tutorial @ theblackips, this tutorial based on javascript and not beginner friendly. If you cannot able to answer any question then cannot answer it. Hope u understand thank you for your respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this code ..It may help you

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#go").click(function(){
            var name    = $("#name").val();
            var pasword = $("#password").val();
            var photos  = $("#photos").val();
            if(name==''||pass==''||photos==''){
              alert("Please Fill All Fields");
            }
            else{
              $.ajax({
                type   : "POST",
                url    : "singup_submit.php",
                data   : formData,
                cache  : false,
                success: function(result){
                alert(result);
                }
              });
            }
            return false;
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending any file in your ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#go").on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        url: 'singup_submit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
                alert(done);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
          },
       });
    });
  });
```

and then take data from global variables in php as you are doing now.
and please assign name to your form fields like so

```
 <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="name" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="pass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Photos:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="img" id="photos"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="go"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank for responding @uzair khan but it not works, when i replace with your ajax then just my url changed. Ex before submit "http://localhost/ajax/singup.php". after submit "http://localhost/ajax/singup.php?img_name=banner2.jpg", and any data not inserted in my data base.

Comment: check your console or go to network tab in google developer tools and look for the response you get.